# Vue.js - Registering the Chart Component via Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I have a Vue.js app. I am trying to use the [vue-charts](https://github.com/hchstera/vue-charts) package. I'm importing the chart module in my index.js file like this:

```
import chartJS from 'chart.js';
import VueCharts from 'hchs-vue-charts';
Vue.use(VueCharts);
```

Then, in my index.vue file, I have the following:

```
<template>
  <div class="page">
    <h2>Hello</h2>

    <chartjs-line></chartjs-line>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {};
        }  
    };
</script>
```

The word "Hello" appears just fine. For that reason, I know that my app is being properly mounted. However, the chart does not appear. When I look in the devtools window, I see the following error:

*Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.*

I assumed when I called `Vue.use`, the component would get registered. However, I'm clearly doing some wrong. Yet, I'm not sure what. How do I use the vue-charts components in my single file components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [How to use in vue components of webpack?](https://github.com/hchstera/vue-charts/issues/19) looks like `vue-charts` doesn't completely support webpack imports, you have to refer to it via `window.VueCharts`.

```
import 'chart.js';
import 'hchs-vue-charts';

Vue.use(window.VueCharts);
```